# Xamarin.Forms: change text size on DatePicker

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, custom-renderer

I created the following custom renderer, but it only changes the selected value size

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(DatePickerCustom), typeof(CustomDatePickerRenderer))]
namespace Vendo.Android.Renderers
{
    public class CustomDatePickerRenderer : DatePickerRenderer
    {
        public CustomDatePickerRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        { }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<DatePicker> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (this.Control == null)
                return;

            Control.TextSize = 16;
        }
    }
}
```

I need to change the text size this way:

[image]

Comment: It's difficult to do that, because the datepicker is content of three numberpicker and the fontsize of the numberpicker is set before it draws. If you want to change the font size of the datepicker, you have to get the numberpicker at first, and then set the fontsize of the numberpicker. Otherwise, you can custom a datepicker and implement the functions of it. Both of them are hard work.